# How to get old Twitter trending topics using Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to get the trending topics (TT) from Twitter from a particular place on a particular date. The first part I got it, but I haven't found a way to go back to get the Tweets from a specific date to get the TT.
I tried this:

```
startDate = datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 0, 0, 0)
endDate = datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 22, 0, 0, 0)

woeid = 368148

trends = []

for trend in tweepy.Cursor(api.trends_place, woeid, since = startDate, until = endDate).items():
    if trend['tweet_volume'] is not None and trend['tweet_volume'] > 1000:
        trends.append((trend['name'], trend['tweet_volume']))
```

which did not work because this method does not support pagination.
Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of information be found in the documentation?

Comment: I tried but was not able to find this information in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historical trends is not something Twitter's API provides.

See:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/old-trends-and-popular-geo-tagged-tweets/11045
https://twittercommunity.com/t/get-historical-trending-topics/134221
https://twittercommunity.com/t/get-historical-trends-data-for-a-particular-location/146011